# How can Heap Pollution cause a security flaw

Tags: java, denial-of-service, secure-coding

I came across this rule in the CERT Secure Coding Standart for Java.
[Heap Pollution](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/OBJ03-J.+Prevent+heap+pollution). I understand this can cause the programm throwing an exception at runtime, but i can't understand how this could cause a security issue like dos or something. Could someone explain an scenario where an attacker could exploit a heap pollution?

Comment: Heap pollution seems to be related to errors in polymorphism, where a variable of one type is cast into its parent's class and then passed incorrectly on a function call.  I would ask the compiler people how this could be exploited.  Perhaps some of them would be on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take the similar example from the [link you quoted](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/OBJ03-J.+Prevent+heap+pollution). In the example i will get the userid (Integer) as argument and try to validate it against database.

```
class ListUtility {
  private static void addToList(List list, Object obj) {
    list.add(obj); // Unchecked warning
  }


  private static boolean validateUser(List list){
     boolean isValidUser=false;
     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); //conn is a jdbc Connection 
     String Query="SELECT userid FROM Customers WHERE userid='"+list.get(0)+"'"; //developer expects list.get(0) is a integer
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(Query);
     if (rs.next()) {
         System.out.println("Valid User");
         isValidUser=true;
       }      
     return isValidUser; //returns true for args[0]=something' or '1'='1
   }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
    addToList(list, args[0]); //arg[0] is expected to be a valid userid of type Integer(say)
    validateuser(list);

  }

}
```

Now If i invoke the program with the argument  `something' or '1'='1` it will print `"Valid User"`. This is a typical Sql Injection. But this has succeeded because of Heap Pollution where we added `args[0]` to `list` even though the type didn't match.

Heap pollution is possible in this case because the parameterized type information is discarded before execution.

The call to `addToList(list,args[0])` succeeds in adding an String to list, although list is of type `List<Integer>`.  Also, the call to `validateUser(List list)` takes the list of type `List<Object>` instead of strict `List<Integer>` .

*This Java runtime does not throw a ClassCastException since the value list was not  read with an invalid type in this example.* 
*Because the list is never read strictly as `List<Integer>`.*

Answer (score 0):

Very unlikely to happen, but possible:

If some programmers mishandle an unchecked warning throwing a `ClassCastException` by casting some unsigned integer values into signed integer that could easily allow an attacker to bypass `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` into an integer overflow attack.